# Unable to boot OSX on failed Ubuntu Installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu onto my Mac OSX as a dual boot, but I'm afraid I've created a bit of a problem for myself. My Macbook now only boots into GNU Grub.

I had installed Ubuntu into a 5 GB partition on my Mac OSX hard drive. Things were great, so I decided to allocate more space to the Ubuntu partition by deleting it, and attempting to recreate it.

I deleted the Ubuntu partition successfully, but then when I restarted my computer it would only boot into GNU Grub. I attempted to boot into Mac OSX by holding down the option key, but Mac OSX did not appear.

I noticed when running efibootmgr, I could see both OSX and OSX recovery as bootable options. However... every time I attempted to boot into them (either for only the next boot, or to set them as primary), the system would hang, and then boot right back into GNU Grub.

I tried resetting the computer's NVRAM, but now Mac OSX and OSX recovery have disappeared completely from efibootmgr, though 0080 does show up with no title.

Current efibootmgr output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* rEFInd boot manager
Boot0080* 
BootFFFF*
```

I figure I should reach out for help before I make things any messier! Ideally, at this point I'd like to be able to boot just back into OSX, and figure out the Ubuntu install another way.

Any ideas?